# How to delete or rollback a cookbook just after creating?

Tags: chef

I just created a cookbook by `knife cookbook create ruby -o site-cookbooks`.

But I noticed after that `rails` is a better naming.

I want to delete the cookbook and create another one. But I couldn't find how to delete it.
Is there way to rollback a `create` action like this situation?

Maybe is it ok, if I simply rename the cookbook folder `ruby` to `rails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the folder that was created, however you'd like.  For example, `rm -rf site-cookbooks/ruby`.

Simply renaming the folder won't quite work, as there will be references to the original name in various cookbook files.  Many of these are just comments, and all can be updated, but in your situation it's easiest to delete and recreate.

Comment: Given the fact that you didn't upload it to the chef server, it is as easy as described by zts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded your cookbook before you need to use

```
knife cookbook delete site-cookbooks/ruby
```